# How to support class methods in interface definitions in Delphi

Tags: delphi, oop, interface

I created a class method in a class that implements an interface, but I can't seem to define it inside of the interface.

```
IMyClass = interface
  procedure someproc();
  class function myfunc() : TMyClass;  // compiler doesn't like this!
end;

TMyClass = class( TInterfacedObject, IMyClass )
public
  procedure someproc();
  class function myfunc() : TMyClass;
end;
```

I want `myfunc()` to create and return an instance of `TMyClass`. For example:

```
somefunc( TMyClass.myfunc(), ... );
```

creates an instance of `TMyClass` and passes it into `somefunc`.

I can define `function myfunc() : TMyClass;` in the IMyClass interface, but if I put `class` in front of it, the compiler gives me an error.  If I leave it off, it gives me several other errors "E2291 Missing implementation of interface method xyz.myfunc" It just doesn't accept the same signature in the interface as in the class.

I thought I've seen this work before (class methods defined in interfaces) but maybe not.

If this isn't supported directly, how do you do it?

(I'm using Delphi XE5, in case it matters.)

Comment: Implement the interface method with an instance method rather than a class method

Comment: It works as an instance method, but it requires an instance rather than the class.

Comment: That's right. You need an instance to implement an interface.

Comment: I've been reading up on some Java 8 features, and they now include ways to define static members (Delphi class methods) within interfaces. I was wondering if there's any way to do it in Delphi.

Comment: Delphi interfaces are COM interfaces and bound by the implementation details of COM

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is a IInterface based Delphi interface still a COM interface? I thought only IUnknown makes them COM compatible.

Comment: @mjn All Delphi interfaces on Windows are COM compatible. They all derive from `IInterface` which, on Windows, is the same as `IUnknown`.

Comment: That doesn't mean the compiler cannot be adapted to accommodate them. As I said, they just added this ability to Java 8. It's just not something I've heard anybody talk about with Delphi.

Comment: @David were talking about what the compiler/language does now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interfaces are not classes and do not support methods marked as `class`, they only support non-`class` methods that are implemented and called on object instances.

What you are looking for will most likely have to be implemented as a class factory instead of using an interface.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible because it violates binary specifications of Delphi interfaces.

Any interface method in Delphi have hidden first parameter - pointer to an instance. Instance methods have the same hidden parameter (`Self`, the same pointer to an instance) and because of this they are binary compatible with interface methods.

On the other hand the hidden parameter of a class method is a pointer to the class vtable, so Delphi class methods are binary incompartible with Delphi interface methods.

Hypothetically you could think of the following (binary compatible) declarations:

```
IMyClass = interface
  procedure someproc();
  function myfunc(): TMyClass;
end;

TMyClass = class( TInterfacedObject, IMyClass )
public
  procedure someproc();
  class function myfunc(Inst: TMyClass) : TMyClass; static;
end;
```

Here I use `static` specifier to remove the hidden parameter (class vtable pointer) we don't need and add the instance pointer parameter explicitely; but the compiler does support such syntax because the above is essentially the same as a simpler

```
IMyClass = interface
  procedure someproc();
  function myfunc(): TMyClass;
end;

TMyClass = class( TInterfacedObject, IMyClass )
public
  procedure someproc();
  function myfunc() : TMyClass;
end;
```

Comment: Well, if there would ever be a change to support class methods in interfaces, it is safe to assume that the binary representation will change to make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class method (class procedure in Delphi) in a class definition (TMyClass)  but **not in an interface** (IMyClass ).

Comment: David is not trying to define a class method in an interface. He's trying to implement an interface method with a class method.